# Searching for a question with [ in the title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, title, special-characters

I [had a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/138951) which was very difficult to find on google, because the question was in reference to the linux command `/usr/bin/[`. Google seems to ignore the `[` part of my search rendering the answer virtually impossible to find.

I had a reasonably good idea what the answer was before I posted it but I wanted to be sure, and I also thought it was a great question to ask specifically because it was so hard to find a good answer. However I not notice that when I [search ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2F%5B) for `/usr/bin/[`, I get no results.

Shouldn't my question appear?

Comment: `[` is used for tag searching, so maybe SOFU ignores it. I would recommend they be smart enough not to though because it is a programmer's search engine after all.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This will get full size : https://i852.photobucket.com/albums/ab87/holocryptic/search.jpg

Comment: I love alt text

Comment: stupid broken links.....

Comment: my post-image-fu sucks....

Comment: stupid Flikr.  If I wanted a thumbnail, I would say so.  Sorry, I'm not social network inclined.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles :-)

Comment: photobucket FTW

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2F[%22+josh+site%3Aserverfault.com

First result:

[What is /usr/bin/[ ? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/138951/what-is-usr-bin)

Comment: Well yes but if you take off the `[` you get the exact same results. I think the fact that I'm #1 is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Try

https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22usr+bin%22